# Equivalency of two sets (set notation)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

Let there be a function $f : A \rightarrow B$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets. It's image is defined as $f(A)=\{f(a)\in B: a\in A\}$.

Would it be equivalent to write $f(A)=\{b\in B: b = f(a), \forall a \in A\}$ and if not why not.

I sometimes find the set notation a little ambiguous, is there a precise reference?

Comment: $b=f(a) , ∃a ∈ A$: for **some** $a \in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is the set of elements in $B$ that are the image of *every* element in $A$. This is a singleton if $f$ is constant and empty otherwise.

Moreover, a possible way to fix the statement is $\{b \in B: \exists a \in A. f(a)=b\}$